# Spectral radius and Dominant Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, spectral-radius

What is the difference between the spectral radius and dominant eigenvalue? 
If they are one and the same then why do both get mentioned, for instance here 
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a matrix, and $\sigma(A)$ signifies the set of all eigenvalues$(\lambda_i)$ of $A$. Then

An eigenvalue of $A$ that is *larger* in absolute value than any other eigenvalue is called the dominant eigenvalue.

But

*Spectral radius* of $A$, which is denoted by $\rho(A)$ is defined as:
$\rho(A) = \max\{|\lambda|:\lambda\ \epsilon\hspace{1mm}\sigma(A)$

Thus, spectral radius is more widely applicable; every matrix has a well defined spectral radius.  Not every matrix has a dominant eigenvalue but there are theorems guaranteeing the existence of a dominant eigenvalue under appropriate conditions; first among these is the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).

Matrices with dominant eigenvalues often arise in numerical approximation schemes for differential equations and the "stiffness" of a system can be quantified in terms of the size of the dominant eigenvalue.  Rather than compute the exact value of the dominant eigenvalue, a numerical scheme might use a cheaper estimate of the spectral radius to determine stiffness.  This is why both terms are mentioned in your link.

Comment: Put it simply, the spectral radius is the modulus of the dominant eigenvalue.

Comment: @user1551 False

Comment: @MarkMcClure I guess it depends on context. In my experience, an eigenvalue is called dominant if it is an (as opposed to *the*) eigenvalue with the largest modulus. Dominant eigenvalues are not necessarily unique. But definitions may vary across areas of research.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, Thanks,for making the answer more meaningful. Which it seems to be now.

Comment: @lavkush No problem!  I was typing up an answer when yours came through.  You hit the crux so I just added some context.

Comment: @user1551 Maybe - Every time I've seen the term 'dominant eigenvalue', it's uniqueness is essential. The [power method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) is a classic example. More to the point, the uniqueness is an essential part of the answer as stated.

Comment: @lavkush But how are the values different? When the spectral radius is defined isn't it also the dominant eigenvalue?

Comment: @lavkush if a matrix has 2 eigenvalues with the same modulus, say complex conjugates, which is the largest, then do we say that the matrix does not have a dominant eigenvalue?

Comment: @Ranade Correct - such a matrix does not have a dominant eigenvalue.